# Progress info from format.com

Tags: vb.net, process, command, progress-bar

I use the following to format a usb drive:

```
FDrive.FileName = "format.com"
        FDrive.Arguments = Mid(TDir, 6, 2) & ForQ & Mid(TDir, 9, 4)
        FDrive.UseShellExecute = False : FDrive.CreateNoWindow = True
        FDrive.RedirectStandardOutput = True : FDrive.RedirectStandardInput = True
        FProcess = Process.GetProcessesByName("format.com")
        TimerX.Enabled = True : TimerX.Start()
        If FormatDriveX.IsBusy = False And Can > 0 Then : FormatDriveX.RunWorkerAsync(x) : End If
```

The Backgroundworker then simply calls the FDrive task to start to format:

```
Process.Start(FDrive)
```

If I started the format from CMD it provides a progress indicator. 
How can I access this value to use in a progressbar?

Comment: Firstly, why are you using all those colons?  You're just making your code harder to read.  You can put an entire `If` statement on one line anyway so it's pointless there and putting two statements on one line elsewhere does nothing useful.

Comment: As for the question, you are presumably redirecting the output stream for a specific reason.  Have you researched how to read from that redirected stream?

Comment: To that end, [this](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?381405) might be useful to you.

Comment: Comments noted - thanks. Will Look into the redirected stream option